# Why SetWindowsHookEx not works in the CLI(which codes in main() instead dllmain,etc.)?

Tags: windows, winapi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { 
 printf("Keyboard event, nCode = %d, wParam = %d, lParam = 0x%.8X\n", nCode, wParam, lParam);
 return (LRESULT)NULL;
} 

void main() { 
 HHOOK HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, (HOOKPROC)KeyboardProc, (HINSTANCE) NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
 printf("Hook handle = 0x%.8X\n", HookHandle);

 MSG message;
 while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
 TranslateMessage(&message);
 DispatchMessage(&message);
 }

 UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookHandle);
}
```

Expected it outputs something like "keyboard event...", but it does not work, it always keep silent whatever I type.

The compile options is simple: gcc -o test.exe test.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) of these hooks have to be injected into the target application(s), so they must be implemented in a DLL.

Comment: So is not possible to capture the key event in console program without a DLL?

Comment: "Capture" isn't very specific.  You can set a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, it doesn't require a DLL.

Comment: WH_KEYBOARD_LL is a global hook, I think it have to be in a DLL as this link says:[link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699)

Comment: @Chen: Actually Hans is right: you don't need a DLL for WH_KEYBOARD_LL, because the handling is done in the process where the hook was created (i.e. the hook is *not* injected in other processes). I'll update my answer.

Comment: It works! but my new question is: why GetCurrentThreadId() not works but 0 works?

Comment: @Chen: it works because the LL hook is global (even though the code is not injected). Global hooks *must* be created using a module handle and a 0 thread ID. Also, I believe you accepted the wrong answer. Check my username; my answer is the other one.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the [KeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644984.aspx) callback function:

> The system calls this function
>   whenever an application calls the
>   GetMessage or PeekMessage function and
>   there is a keyboard message (WM_KEYUP
>   or WM_KEYDOWN) to be processed.

Console applications don't use the message queue to handle input, so your hook will never be called.

You could try using a low-level keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL). Even though that's a global hook, you don't need to use a DLL: as mentioned in the Remarks section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985.aspx), the hook code is not injected in other processes. The problem with this approach of course is that you'll get notifications for all key events in the system (not just the ones in your program).

Comment: hm.. seems I cannot post linebreak text in the reply. I wanted to post some codes which can getmessage() with registerhotkey(). I think that means message queue should work in console application?

Comment: @Chen, message queues work just fine in console apps. `RegisterHotKey()` causes WM_HOTKEY to be sent and you can handle it in the msg loop as usual. The problem is that *console keyboard input* does not generate any WM_KEYUP/DOWN messages, so it cannot be trapped by WH_KEYBOARD.

Comment: I changed WH_KEYBOARD to WH_KEYBOARD_LL. But still not works. And I want to get all key events in the system.

Comment: @Chen, did you set the correct module and thread ID? `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(0), 0)` should do the trick.